# How does the VTP Client update it's information if the revision number is equal?

Tags: vlan, networking, vtp

I am new to networking and my questions may be a bit weird.

Please correct me if I am wrong. According to what I understand, Client updates it's information with the Server's if the Server's revision number is larger. Mostly they recommend to take the switch to transparent mode to reset the revision number. I wonder, what happens if the revision number is the same. How does the VLAN information change according to it?

Sorry if my question is weird. Like I said I am very new.

Comment: I just want to add a note that it's typically a best practice to effectively disable VTP by setting your switches into transparent mode so you lessen the risk of accidentally propagating the wrong VLANs onto the wrong switches, or that accidentally deleting a VLAN on the core doesn't cascade to the member switches and make things much worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rev number is identical, the client assumes it's already got the latest config and there's no update. You'll need to reset the client to make it update.

Answer (score 0):

you need to know what trigger update, in stable topology all switches revision number are in sync ie.they have same revision number,like zac said resting the client will make the revision number zero, if switch see revision number 0, and vtp updates come to it from whatever switches it connects to it , it will compare revision numbers if the update is larger than it is own revision number it will update it's database